# How to use GridLayout codrrect in platform IOS Nativescript

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, grid-layout

I have this code. In android work very good, in IOS I can't change map.

```
<GridLayout class="page">
        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="*,auto,auto">
            <StackLayout col='0' row='0'>
                <MapView class="map" (mapReady)="onMapReady1($event)" (markerSelect)="onMarkerSelect($event)"
                    (cameraChanged)="onCameraChanged($event)"></MapView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout class="input-field" col='0' row='0' style="margin-top: 10">
                <GridLayout columns="*,*" rows="*">
                    <StackLayout col='0' row='0'>
                        <DropDown itemsTextAlignment="center" itemsPadding="10" title="Comune di:" hint="Comune di:"
                            [items]="citiess" (selectedIndexChanged)="onchangecity($event)" (opened)="onopen()"
                            (closed)="onclose()"
                            style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.918); border-color:slategray; padding: 3%;
                            font-size: 18; color: rgb(70, 70, 70); size: 14px; margin-left: 6%; margin-top: 0.7%; border-style: solid; text-align: center;">
                        </DropDown>
                    </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </GridLayout>
```

When I put DropDown outside GridLayout, I can change map, but I want to put over map a button  that call dropdown.

Have you any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Your `StackLayout` is overlaying on the whole of `MapView`. In iOS all topmost views block events from propagating below. So only the topmost `StackLayout` after `MapView` receives your click/drag event even though you are not explicitly listening for it.

You can just have the `DropDown` element with exact width and height it needs to occupy and align it by using margins. This will prevent anything else overlaying on the `MapView`.

On a sidenote: If you just want to overlay other elements while keeping the bottom element interactable you can add `isUserInteractionEnabled="false"` to the overlay element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to it  in here `<StackLayout isUserInteractionEnabled="false" class="input-field" col='0' row='0' style="margin-top: 10">..` Map works, but DropDown doesn't work. I want to work DropDown and Map

Comment: Read the 2nd paragraph. You should have the DropDown element directly as the 2nd child of GridLayout with a fixed size. No StackLayouts. Then use margins to align it properly.